# Optimization with LINGO

Tags: optimization, dynamic-programming, linear-programming, lindo

[The Dynamic Programming Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEmj4.jpg)

I have one optimization problem I am trying to solve with LINGO, I am a beginner with LINGO and I need some help. The question can be accessed by cliking on the 'The Dynamic Programming Problem' link above. Sorry I cant embedd images yet.

I tried to script some code to solve the problem but get syntax errors all the time. Could you give me some hint? Thanks

```
    sets:

    people/a,b,c,d/: pb;
    trip(people, people): time;

    endsets

    data: 

    pb = 1, 2, 5, 10;

    time = 

    0   2   5   10
    0   0   5   10
    0   0   0   10
    0   0   0   0;

    enddata

    min = @sum(trip(i,j): time);
```

I also tried this but didnt work

```
   trip/ab, ac, ad, bc, cd/: time;
   solo/a, b, c/: time2;
   link(trip,solo,trip,solo,trip);
   endsets

   data: 
   time = 2, 5, 10, 5, 10;
   time2 = 1, 2, 5;

   enddata

   t1 = @sum(trip:solo:trip:solo:trip);

   Min = @sum(link(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first program runs without any syntax errors on my machine.

The only things missing are: "MODEL:" as the first line of the file, and "END" as the last line.

Comment: Thanks but the optimized answer is 17 but the model gives 42. Can I modify it to obtain the correct result?